# WUBI installed Ubuntu not showing up at boot menu after Windows reinstallation

Tags: 12.04, boot, wubi, bootloader

I recently installed 12.04 using WUBI installer in a separate partition. Because of some problem, I had to reinstall my Windows.

Now the problem is that my Windows has recovered, but Ubuntu is not showing up at the boot menu, even though the Ubuntu partition is intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy `root.disk` file (this contains all your Ubuntu data) from your Ubuntu installation drive using live USB or anything.
2. Re-install Ubuntu into the same partition (drive) with WUBI.
3. Once installation is complete, copy/move back the `root.disk` file from the backup you made.

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall Ubuntu  because when you formatted windows drive , your ubuntu boot entries are deleted which were present in previous windows. You should  delete ubuntu files of previous installation in drive where you installed Ubuntu using wubi for space. They aren't more usable now.

Comment: sir kuch toh upay hoga??

Comment: Are dost me Upay to bataya fir se install karo..., Uske alava koi upay nahi hai....

Comment: Wubi installation tu jo kuya hai wo just Ubuntu windows ke under try karne ke liye hai....

Comment: "Upay" wow!. The above "Upay" by Vikash Singh appears promising.